# Using regular expressions to do mass replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace quotation marks in a big file in this cases:

Replace:

> M 100644 367cb229 "DFA/OETK/oetk_settings/Sony DADC Demo_with_pass.p12"

By:

> M 100644 367cb229 DFA/OETK/oetk_settings/Sony DADC Demo_with_pass.p12

But I don´t want to replace all the quotation marks of the document, only this specific cases.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does that line occur multiple times in your file?

Comment: How exactly does this case differ from all the other cases where there are quotation marks?

Comment: Could you show some more examples of positive and negative matches?

Comment: The pattern is: M 123456 "text"

Comment: I want to replace theese quotation mark cases but for example not theese one: DSSENGINE-216 DSSENGINE-220 fixed strange "extern C" bug

Comment: The pattern hapens many times in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Find expression:

```
(M \d{6} [^"]*)"([^"]*)"
```

And this Replace expression

```
$1$2
```

I this the first part `(M \d{6} [^"]*)` selects `M 100644 367cb229` - *character M followed by 6 numbers and then anything till a* `"`.

The second part `([^"]*)` selects `DFA/OETK/oetk_settings/Sony DADC Demo_with_pass.p12` - *the text within the quotes*.

Any text within parenthesis is captured by `$1`, `$2`, etc and can be used in replace.

See if this matches for all cases

Comment: Thank you! I finally used your expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this as pattern

```
^(?=M \d{6}\b)(.*?)"(.*?)"
```

and this as replacement

```
$1$2
```

`^` is matching the start of the row

`(?=M \d{6}\b)` is a positive lookahead assertion, that ensures that the row starts with `M \d{6}`

`\d{6}` are six digits

`\b` is a wordboundary, it ensures, that there is a non word character after the last digit, otherwise it would be also true if there are more than 6 digits.

`(.*?)` is matching as less as possible till the following pattern. What is matched is stored and that string can be retrieved by using `$1` for the first group, `$2` for the second group, ...